# Declaring object type list in class file giving "missing a using directive or assembly reference” error

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, class, object

I am getting the titled error when I declare a list with object type in a class file in my Asp.Net web application. I have other classes running so the class system does work. The same declaration is fine in a webform c# code behind. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;  
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TriviaUtilities
/// </summary>
public class TriviaClass
{
    public TriviaClass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void getRegistration()
    {       
        List<Activity> sampleREG = new List<Activity>();       
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Declaring `List<int> sampleREG = new List<int>()` or `List<string> sampleREG = new List<string>()` in the class file poses no problem and this works in a webform also as expected. Declaring the type as an object gives the namespace error in the class file but in the webform it is fine. Since it works on the webform and I have the same namespaces in both the webform and class files, I am suspecting that fixing this is complicated and it needs someone with a higher scope of programming to help with it.

Comment: This doesn’t really help. What’s the full text of the error?

Comment: Maybe you missed including the namespace for your Activity class

Comment: Maybe you need to include any usings for custom classes created within your project

Comment: If the `Activity` class is defined like this `TriviaClass` class, then it's in the global namespace. That means it would have to be referenced like `global::Activity`. But the better solution in that case would be to put your classes inside of a namespace.

Comment: @stuartd Come on guys, stop the negativities. I've already stated that I have other classes working and the stated error is quite clear. Please stop giving comments that are not useful.

Comment: @Rainbolt Come on guys, stop the negativities. I've already stated that I have other classes working and the stated error is quite clear. Please stop giving comments that are not useful.

Comment: @Quergo I have stated though that the same code works in a c# code behind webform.

Comment: @CaptainWibble Let's just wait for an answer. There's something different about using the class file I suspect.

Comment: @matt2605 Does the error message gives any further hint whether the List or the Activity type is the problem? What editor/IDE are you using?

Comment: @matt2605 I don't know what I said that came across as negative. Did you try either of my suggestions? Can you post the `Activity` class definition? You can only access classes by fully qualified name (`Foo.Bar.Activity`), or by including its namespace via a using statement (`using Foo.Bar;`), or by declaring it in the same namespace or a parent namespace. `TriviaClass` does none of those, and so the compiler can't figure out what this thing called `Activity` is.

Comment: The edit says you have the same namespace on both the web forms and class files. The `TriviaClass` class has no namespace, so that's not possible.

Comment: @Rainbolt See my update. As I suspected that has to be twist to the way the code is used. So do I use the using statement of the namespace of any of the the namespaces that I have declared? Any chance that you can show and example?

Comment: Can we discuss in the chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184061/discussion-for-https-stackoverflow-com-q-53421447-3224483

Comment: @Rainbolt I must be getting confused with namespace and a using directive (and maybe an assembly reference). Am I expecting too much of a solution from this - is the answer too simple?

Comment: @Rainbolt Sure. I'm there now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Rainbolt, Captain Wibble, Quergo. The original use of the object type for the list is in a web page that contains 3000 lines. Buried in there was the Activity class that the IDE was looking for, for the Activity object type of the list.
See [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-class) to create a class.